# Creating a list of integers, adding the list and displaying the sum

Tags: python, list

This program is supposed to ask the user for the sales for multiple days, write them to a list, then add those entries together and display the sum.

I have the program to the point that it will ask for sales, but my math and the ultimate display is just not coming out right. Any help would be appreciated.

Than you in advance

```
num_days = 5
def main():
    sales = [0] * num_days
    index = 0
    print('Enter the sales for each day.')
    while index < num_days:
        print('Sales for day #', index + 1, ': ', sep='', end='')
        sales[index] = float(input())
        index = index + 1
        print('the total is', sales)

 main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line `print('the total is', sales)` prints the entire list of individual `sales` items.

You want to use `print('the total is', sum(sales))`, and do that outside of the loop.

Also, you don't need the first `print()`; simply do

```
sales[index] = float(input("Sales for day #{}: ".format(index+1)))
```

And finally, you don't need to build your list of `sales` items in advance. Something like this would be more Pythonic:

```
def main(num_days=5):
    sales = []
    print('Enter the sales for each day.')
    for day in range(num_days):
        sales.append(float(input("Sales for day #{}: ".format(day+1))))
    print('the total is', sum(sales))

main()
```

Comment: quick. thats how to get to 127k. +1